# Address location in Google Maps goes to middle of street

Tags: google-maps

I have a business location (Google Place).  I have claimed the location, provided the address, and verified the location (postcard sent to address).  When I google the business name, the correct address and location are returned.  When I google only the address, the map marker goes to the middle of the road.  It does not give any indication that the address is associated with our business location.  What can I do to get the address to correctly return our business location?

Mapquest and Yahoo maps work correctly.

I've tried googling to see what I can do, and from what I've been able to tell, this could be resolved with Google Map Maker.  The problem with that is Map Maker was closed March 31, 2017.  Google directs me to make the change in Google Maps.  However, Google Maps wants me to add it as a place.  I've already added it as a place with the corresponding address.

Is this something that will fix itself if I wait a period of time?

EDIT:
Here is a gif of what I'm having issues with:
[image: SEC location gif]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you try with the Feedback option on the map.

1. Search for your place in Google Maps
2. Press **Send Feedback** on the bottom right side of the window
3. Choose the relevant option (either **Suggest an Edit to...** or **Edit the Map**)
4. Drag the address pointer to the right location. And **Submit**

Below are two examples how I'm doing it. First is for an address number, 2nd is for a business name:

[image: Business]

[image: Residential]

Comment: The problem is when I search the address, it doesn't even recognize the address as a valid address, it just changes it to the middle of the road.  And if I try adding the address, it wants to add it as a place.  I'll see if I can show an example.  It's worth noting that this is in a rural area.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a gif.